# Como ativar o hover sem criar um arquivo css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, alguém poderia nós auxiliar nesta questão, estou tentando ativar o hover para alterar Background-color, se tem como ativar o hover sem criar um arquivo css.

```html
<body>
       <div> 
        <img  style="float: left;" src="img/logo-topo.png">
        <div style="background-color: rgb(40,39,44); width: 100%;text-align: right; padding-bottom: 0.9px;">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><p style="color: #9acccb;padding-bottom: 2%; padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 1%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Fale Conosco</p></a>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="teste" style="background-color: rgb(44,43,49); padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
          <fieldset style="display: inline-block;width: 40%; height: 20%; border-radius: 50px; border: 3px solid #565262;"><input style="height: 40px; width: 60%; background-color: rgb(44,43,49); border: none;" type="text" placeholder="PROCURE PRODUTOS"><div style="background-color: rgb(221,205,42); float: right; border: 3px solid rgb(221,205,42); width: 125px; border-radius: 15px; height: 35px;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: black; " href="#"><b style="font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">Buscar<span style="width: 5px ;height: 6px; color: #003d85;" class="material-icons"> search </span></b></a></div></fieldset>
          (ADICIONAR O HOVER AQUI PARA ALTERAR BACKGORUND-COLOR)  <div style="margin-right: 10px; float: right; display: inline-block; border: 3px solid rgb(68,227,186); width: 14%; height: 40px; background-color: #44e3ba; border-radius: 50px;"><a href="#" style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;"><span  style="color: rgb(56,66,49);" class="material-icons"> shopping_cart </span><b style=" padding-left: 3px; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(56,66,49); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">CARRINHO DE COMPRAS</b></a></div>
          (ADICIONAR O HOVER AQUI PARA ALTERAR BACKGORUND-COLOR )  <div style="margin-right: 10px; float: right; display: inline-block; border: 3px solid rgb(68,227,186); width: 10%; height: 40px; background-color: #44e3ba; border-radius: 50px;"><a href="#" style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;"><span  style="color: rgb(56,66,49);" class="material-icons"> people_outline </span><b style=" padding-left: 3px; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(56,66,49); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Área do Cliente</b></a></div>            
        </div>
       </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Não eh possível usar pseudo classes no style inline. Cria uma tag Athos no head e cria o :hover lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito acima, não é possível criar pseudo classes no estilo inline, ou seja, o estilo que fica aplicado diretamente na tag. Mas no seu arquivo HTML entre as tags `head`(é indicado que seja entre elas, não obrigatório, pode ser dentro do `body`) você pode criar uma folha de estilo sem precisar criar um arquivo css.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .minhaclass:hover{
        background: #333333;
        color: #FFF;
    }
</style>
```

Para questão de manutenções futuras, sugiro o uso de um arquivo css.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica